# Why does CLR create new class for anonymous method?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, anonymous-methods

I am using anonymous functions in my projects no less. And till know I was thinking that, C# compiler generates just a method using the code used for the anonymous method **in the same class**. But, after decompiling this code in IL, I saw that CLR created a new class.

```
public class Comparer
{
    public delegate int Greater(int a, int b);

    public int Great(Greater greater, int a, int b)
    {
        return greater(a, b);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int valueOfA = 11,
        valueOfB = 23,
        valueOfC = 42;

    Comparer comparer = new Comparer();

    Console.WriteLine("The greater is \t:{0}",
        comparer.Great(delegate(int a, int b)
        {
            int[] numbers = new int[] { a, b, valueOfC };
            return Math.Max(Math.Max(a, b), valueOfC);
        },
        valueOfA, valueOfB));
}
```

Here is decompiled IL code of the **Main** method:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       65 (0x41)
  .maxstack  5
  .locals init ([0] int32 valueOfA,
           [1] int32 valueOfB,
           [2] class Ch04.Comparer comparer,
           [3] class Ch04.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass1' 'CS$<>8__locals2') // Here it is    
   ...
}
```

Comment: I don't think .NET supports "free floating" methods, they always have to be contained within a class.  The compiler is just creating a container to hold the method.

Comment: Not just to hold the method, but also to maintain state.

Comment: ...and a place to store any captured variables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is nothing to capture it C# compiler will create private method in the class, if you have variables in closure - inner class will be created.

Covered in details in [Chapter 12 - Delegates and Lambda Expressions](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/FreeBookArticles/AddisonWesley/2009Oct13001134AM/DelegatesLambda/7.aspx)

```
int local = 42;
...Where(value => {return true;})... // private method
...Where(value => { return value == local;})... // class
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking about it. But, not found exactly this sentence in anywhere. Also, I have one question. Why then it does not create captured variable inside the method?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev - I've added link and sample. You may also find Eric Lippert's [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/01/10/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-one.aspx) interesting. One more easy to read writeup on the topic of many http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/12/internals-of-delegate.html

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev It can't possibly create captured variable inside a method. Captured variables need to be implemented somehow and obviously they can't be implemented with captured variables.